# Can you turn a string to a function in lua

Tags: lua

This sounds like a really weird question but I want to do something like this:

```
local var = encode("loadstring")
if decode(var) == loadstring then
var("print('Hello')")
end
```

So I want it to encode a string which is "loadstring" and check if it is loadstring and then use that var to execute a script.

Sorry if that was a bad explanation but english is not my first language

Answer (score 1):

It's enough to do this:

```
local var = loadstring
if var == loadstring then
  var("print('Hello')") -- this is doesn't quite do what you need, but the call itself is correct
end
```

You can save and compare the value of `loadstring` as you'd do any other value in Lua. Lua functions are [first-class values](https://www.lua.org/pil/6.html).